# Why doesn't the result of running java file appear in the terminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have downloaded the 6 required extensions as mentioned on the vsc website
and download jdk-20
And when I press run, a notification of the process of building and running comes below the program, but the terminal tab does not appear to show the result of the code
When I deleted jdk, vsc told me, so I downloaded it again

-- The problem is not that there are errors, but that the result of the operation does not appear. why?

I tried to run a very simple java file on vsc but the code result is not shown

The number on the run and debug flag is the number of times the file has been run but there was no result:

[image: The number on the run and debug flag is the number of times the file has been run but there was no result]

The operation ends with no result:

[image: The operation ends with no result]

Comment: Do not include screenshots of code. Copy and paste the code into your post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by downloading the `code runner extension`, but the result appeared in output, not in the terminal. [Solve the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3QfR.jpg)

Thank you!